# Why do child divs extend beyond their parent div?

Tags: html, css

I feel stupid asking this but this is a very simple problem that don't understand how to solve.  In the code below, why are the container, main, and secondary divs extending beyond the header?  I understand that it's occurring because of the padding I've assigned to the container but I've assigned a max-width to the html element.  The header element is obeying that maximum width but the container and its child divs aren't.  I've looked at similar questions here but didn't see anything that I thought pertained to my particular situation. What's going on here?

Thanks.

[image]

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../reset.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            max-width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
        }
        header { 
            height: 2.5em;
            background: #2a3744; 
            color: #fff;
        }
        body {
            font-size: 100%;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .container {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 1em;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background: #ccc;
        }
        .main { background: #cf6; }
        .secondary { background: #fc6; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header role="banner">
        header
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main">
            main           
        </div>
        <div class="secondary">
            secondary
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `padding: 1em` on the container  together with the `width:100%` makes the actual width `100% + 2em`.

You should add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.container` to make sure that the width is 100% ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/esjk7qq2/)).

Comment: Or just remove the `width:100%` declaration from the container. It's a div so it's 100% wide by default.

Comment: [Browser compatability](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing) - `box-sizing:border-box` is available in IE8 (with some issues) and IE9+.

Comment: I see.  But I have box-sizing set in the body selector.  Since the container is in the body, I would think it would be governed by the body's box-sizing selector.

Comment: @Robert `box-sizing` applies to the element, and is not inherit by descendant nodes. You have to explicitly set `box-sizing:border-box;` to an element before it applies, e.g. `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`.